# Error al hacer peticion http desde Angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, typescript

A la hora de realizar una petición a través de angular a un servidor NodeJS (ambos en local), no recibo ninguna respuesta. Sin embargo, si lo hago a través de Insomnia (Una app tipo Postman) me funciona perfectamente.

El método de la api es `updateUser`:

```
  updateUser = (user: Object) =>
  {
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/updateuser', user );
  };
```

Este método es llamado desde el método modifyUser. modifyUser recibe un parametro NgForm y lo envía al método:

```
  modifyUser =  (f: NgForm) =>{
    this.connectionService.updateUser(f.form.value as Object)
  }
```

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los observables se ejecutan hasta el momento de hacer subscribe, mira más sobre rxjs

```
  modifyUser =  (f: NgForm) =>{
    this.connectionService.updateUser(f.form.value as Object).subscribe();
  }
```